# нужна помощь с регуляркой [list]

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

пробую написать свой парсер для замещения на теги. и вот проблема. нужно вот это

```
[list]
[*] hello
[*] привет
[/list]
```

сделать с так, чтобы я мог заменить это на такой текст.

```
<ul>
<li> hello </li>
<li> привет </li>
</ul>
```

я сначала пробывал в ide это делать, но проверять долго. потом нашел сайт где можно проверить на совпадения по регулярке. И вот уже на этом месте ошибка. вот что я смог сделать.

```
\[list\]{1}(\[*\]([a-z]+){0,})
```

и ничего не определяется, я пока плохо знаю регулярки. можно ли вообще заменить как я хочу?

Обновлено.

я составил такую регулярку, вроде правильная.
вот какая получилась.

```
((\[list\]){1})*((\[[*]\]{1}.*)([a-z]+)*){0,}((\[\/list\]){1})*
```

теперь как мне получить доступ к элементу, который находится после [*]?

Comment: блин, не подходит такая регулярка.

Comment: Начните по частям. Сначала получите внутренность list, а потом разбейте на части (split)

Comment: Не получится так, с одним выражением. Если у вас есть вложенные списки, лучше просто напишите парсер. Можно и с регулярными выражениями, но не одним.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот пример

```
$re = '/\[list\](.*?)\[\/list\]/s';
$re_items='/\[\*\]\s(.*?)$/m';

$str = '
[list]
[*] hello
[*] привет
[/list]
[list]
[*] hello1
[*] привет2
[/list]';

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);

if ( count($matches) == 0 ) {
        echo "Matched nothing!\n";
    } else {
        foreach ($matches[1] as $val) {
          preg_match_all($re_items, $val, $items, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER, 0);
          echo "<ul>\n";
            foreach ($items[1] as $item){
              echo "<li>$item</li>\n";  


            }
          echo "<\ul>\n";
        }

    }
```

Вывод

```
<ul>
<li>hello
</li>
<li>привет
</li>
</ul>
<ul>
<li>hello1
</li>
<li>привет2
</li>
</ul>
```

Вообще у вас вариант BBcode. Лучше использовать готовый [парсер](https://github.com/chriskonnertz/bbcode).

Более [подробно](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.bbcode.php) о BBcode.

Comment: не, готовый не подходит. у меня подключается библиотека на js, в которой можно указать что я буду использовать в теге <code>, например <code class="c++">, и так получается что с bbcode появляются проблемы, я немного посмотрел код, но так и не понял как исправить, чтобы мой тег <code> он не трогал.

Comment: Я всё таки использую ту bbcode, которую вы посоветовали. а там лицензия mit, скажите, я могу изменить код в этой bbcode и выложить на свой сервер? я нашел что надо поменять.

Comment: Я не знаком подробно с этой лицензией. Но если она на гитхабе, то скорее всего можно

Comment: да я почитал уже эту лицензию. можно менять код. что я и сделал. теперь можно использовать и bbcode и highlightjs.  http://s1.uploadpics.ru/images/Z1qC8ch9dH.png